# Python requests allow_redirects не работает

Tags: python

При GET запросе URL-ы с помощью [request](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) для python получаю статус код 200, но если открываю этот URL в браузере, то отдается 302 Redirect.

```
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
```

Comment: r.history возвращает пустой массив

Comment: Возможно, сервер фильтрует какие-то заголовки или User-Agent.

Comment: @nomnoms12 действительно, сервер фильтровал User-Agent.
Добавил user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} 
 r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False, headers = user_agent) параметром в GET, и помогло. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Сервер фильтровал User-Agent. Добавил User-Agent в вызов запроса и получил корректный статус код (302 Redirect).

```
   user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
   r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False, headers = user_agent)
```